# Ebean transaction propagation with Play Framework 2.2.2

Tags: transactions, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm trying to use transactions with Ebean and Play Framework 2.2.2.
Since @Transactional annotation does not work in the methods of my services (I suppose they are not enhanced as explained in Ebean documentation), I tried to manage transactions manually.

I have this code :

```
public void method1() {
    Ebean.beginTransaction();
    try {
        // Do something
        // Do something else
        method2();
        Ebean.commitTransaction();
    }
    finally {
        Ebean.endTransaction();
    }
}

public void method2() {
    Ebean.beginTransaction();
    try {
        doSomething();
        Ebean.commitTransaction();
    }
    finally {
        Ebean.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

With this code, I have the following error when I begin the transaction in `method2` :

`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: The existing transaction is still active?`

How do I define propagation of the transactions when declaring them manually, as I would do with @Transactional ?
My `method2` can be called in `method1` and from somewhere else so I can't remove the transaction in it...

Answer (score 0):

Ebean.beginTransaction(); method returns a Transaction object.

So, if you change the inside of your methods like the may help:

```
Transaction t = Ebean.beginTransaction();
try {
    doSomething();
    t.commit();
}
finally {
    t.end();
}
```

Comment: That does not change anything as Ebean manages one transaction at a time (see Ebean.currentTransaction()). So even if, I use a variable, the transaction will be registered. I'm trying to find if I can use REQUIRED, REQUIRES_NEW, MANDATORY...

Answer (score 0):

Try begin another transaction on method 2

replace

```
@Transactional
public void method2() {..}
```

with

```
@Transactional(type = TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void method2() {..}
```

or

```
TxScope txScope = TxScope.requiresNew();

public void method2() {
      Ebean.execute(txScope, new TxRunnable() {
      public void run() {
        ..
      }
}
```

you may find these suggestions here:
http://www.avaje.org/doc/ebean-userguide.pdf

and it is correct that
Ebean has one active transaction per EbeanServer per Thread.